# Difference between src/folder and folder in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I see projects that have `src/folder` and just `folder` - **both being source folders**.  What is the difference and how does one get a `src/` source folder structure.  I cannot find anything that speaks specifically about this folder structure.

Example:
How to get a folder structure like this:

[image]

When using New -> Source Folder I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, `src/folder` is automatically added to the build path of the project, whereas normal folder isn't.

In general, Eclipse creates a `src` folder as the default parent source folder. All other folders which are meant to contain source files should be placed inside the same `src` folder. Doing this will result in folder structure as desired in the question.

Comment: It does not.  Even when I use the menu New>Source Folder from within the src folder.  It always adds it to the parent directory.